# ASP MVC5 OnActionExecuting RedirectToRouteResult causes infinite loop

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-routing

I have a filter attribute that checks for a route parameter and if it doesn't exits I apply some logic to check if the current request needs to be redirected to another route.

My code looks like this

```
Public Overrides Sub OnActionExecuting(filterContext As ActionExecutingContext)
            If Not filterContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("SearchKey") Then
                strSearchKey = strFrom.ToString.Substring(strFrom.ToString.IndexOf("/") + 1)
                strFrom = strFrom.ToString.Substring(0, strFrom.ToString.IndexOf("/") + 1)
                If Not IsNullOrEmpty(strSearchKey) Then
                    Dim values As New Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary
                    values.Add("SearchKey", strSearchKey)
                    values.Add("From", strFrom)
                    values.Add("controller", "SearchResults")
                    values.Add("action", "Category")
                    filterContext.Result = New RedirectToRouteResult("SearchCategory", values)
                    'filterContext.Result.ExecuteResult(filterContext)
                End If
            End If
End Sub
```

This is what I'm doing to get it to redirect but the problem is that it causes an infinite loop and I can't find the reason why it just keeps hitting this same route which is the one I'm redirecting from over and over.

Comment: I think you have to check for the action name  and controller name before redirecting, otherwise it will cause an infinite loop.
Remember taht SearchCategory is an action also.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?@MajdiSabi

Comment: @MajdiSaibi I'm already checking that... the action with this particular filter is "CategoryMenu"  im redirecting it to Search Category but that never happens the infinite loop says the action name still CategoryMenu

Comment: This happen because of  request passes through the same filter, so when you redirect to Category action it again call the OnActionResult method. so somehow you have to avoid that too many redirect.